# jquery autocomplete results to html/div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, autocomplete

I need to output results from a database to jquery autocomplete that will put the results dynamically into html as the user types the search.

1) html tags of input and div elements

2) javascript/jquery 
 
a) calls to call the json url for getting data
 
b) jquery/javascript to fill html div tags list (and remove elements as they search broadens.

Search Name: Hitlon

i've searched for similar questions but can't find a complete solution.  this is similar to Google search results.

HTML output would be div tags that show Trade Name and Location in the results on the same page.

```js
var myJSONObject = {"searchResults": [
        {"id": "10", "permit": "MB863880", "trade_name": "HILTON GARDEN INN", "location":"4449 RIDGEMONT DR ABILENE, TX, 79606"},
        {"id": "213", "permit": "MB850728", "trade_name": "HILTON GARDEN INN - ADDISON", "location":"4090 BELT LINE RD ADDISON, TX, 75001"},
        {"id": "273", "permit": "RM766705", "trade_name": "HILTON GARDEN INN-ALLEN", "location":"705 CENTRAL EXPY S ALLEN, TX, 75013"}
    ]
};
```

Comment: check out this tutorial: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-step-by-step

Comment: thanks but what i'm trying to do is display the results into div elements on the page and not the input search box.  i didnt see that in the examples.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer not to code for you but I can take you through this.

Since you have the Service response as JSON object what you need to do now is these steps:

1. In javascript iterate an array over the json response.
2. create html element div dynamically and concat the JSON field data into it.
3. Append it to your already defined div (your search result container).

Let me know if you need to know how to iterate over JSON Object

Comment: i agree, i need to get in an code it.  i'll be back with solution and see if anyone has a way to make it better

Comment: Sure thing! Keep going!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jquery .each() method to loop over your json object

```
var myJSONObject = {"searchResults": [
        {"id": "10", "permit": "MB863880", "trade_name": "HILTON GARDEN INN", "location":"4449 RIDGEMONT DR ABILENE, TX, 79606"},
        {"id": "213", "permit": "MB850728", "trade_name": "HILTON GARDEN INN - ADDISON", "location":"4090 BELT LINE RD ADDISON, TX, 75001"},
        {"id": "273", "permit": "RM766705", "trade_name": "HILTON GARDEN INN-ALLEN", "location":"705 CENTRAL EXPY S ALLEN, TX, 75013"}
    ]
};

$.each(myJSONObject.searchResults, function(i, item) {
    $('body').append('<div>'+item.trade_name+'</div>')
})
```

The bottom function will append a div, with each items trade name, you can extrapolate that to print other things